# Google maps directions traffic time is lower than normal

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Using the google DirectionsService, I get the following result in my route's leg:

[image]

How come the duration with traffic is less than the normal duration? Can someone explain what these values are because this result is confusing.

I'm looking for the time it will take without considering traffic, so I can get that (which is 53m as well) by not providing the `drivingOptions`. But I noticed the above and is curious about it.

Does it mean that the normal duration of 53m is actually a general and average time considering traffic? and the duration_in_traffic at that time (4am) is then actually more accurate because there is no traffic? Should I then rather use the 51m if I'm looking for time without traffic?

Answer (score 0):

Is it more accurate? Well it depends if you really want to know the duration at 4am. If that's what you aim for, then yes it *should* be more accurate.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Kindly note that

> Note: The `durationInTraffic` field is now deprecated. It was previously the recommended way for Google Maps APIs Premium Plan customers to specify whether the result should include a duration that takes into account current traffic conditions. You should now use the `drivingOptions` field instead.

You can also read more here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DrivingOptions

As the documentation says, the `duration` field is an *estimate* so I'd guess they make an average of the duration at different times of the day but I can't confirm that.